# Extracting the copyable identity of the non-copyable object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to use non-copyable objects as keys in the `NSMutableDictionary` which, by default, is not allowed. I understand the reasons for this not being allowed (retaining the key object, unlike the value object, is undesirable), but it seems like in my particular situation there could be a way around this.

The thing is that I'm only need to query the dictionary using the key's address, i.e. having the lookup predicate

```
if (providedKey == storedKey)
```

instead of

```
if ([providedKey isEqual:storedKey])
```

would be perfectly sufficient.

Is there a way of extracting the object's reference address (or other form of identity) as a copyable comparable object which I could use as a dictionary key instead of the object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [`+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-valueWithPointer_) might be what you want. It stores the pointer itself in an object that conforms to `NSCopying`, so that you can use it as a dictionary key. Retrieve the pointer using `pointerValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", someObject]` as your key.
This will create a string with the object's address as a hex value.

Comment: Another option might be `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Thanks! It seems like your answer is the most appropriate. Could you please add it as an answer (not as a comment), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an nsnumber that represents the hash of the object.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop down to the CoreFoundation APIs and define you own callbacks (among other things).

NSMutableDictionary is a CFMutableDictionary.

specifically, you want to create a CFMutableDictionary, and define your own `CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks`.